# musl fails to link libc.a into shared library

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, musl

I have a C99 shared library that I want to link in a few statically static libraries (via `--whole-archive`). **Note**: All the static libs are built with `-fPIC`

I also would like to build a universal linux binary and thus have decided to use musl. When I try to link in the static `libc.a` from musl I get the following error:

```
# Building shared library tgt/Linux-x86_64/mylib/lib/mylib.so
/root/mylib/./tgt/Linux-x86_64/libmusl/bin/musl-gcc -Wl,-whole-archive -L./tgt/Linux-x86_64/libmusl/lib -L./tgt/Linux-x86_64/libz/lib -L./tgt/Linux-x86_64/libssl/lib -L./tgt/Linux-x86_64/libsasl/lib -L./tgt/Linux-x86_64/librdkafka/lib -L./tgt/Linux-x86_64/libcurl/lib -L./tgt/Linux-x86_64/libgjalloc/lib -L./tgt/Linux-x86_64/libavro/lib -L./tgt/Linux-x86_64/libunwind/lib -l:libc.a -l:libpthread.a -l:libz.a -l:libssl.a -l:libcrypto.a -l:libsasl2.a -l:libm.a -l:librt.a -l:libcrypt.a -l:libunwind-x86_64.a -l:librdkafka.a -l:libcurl.a -l:libgjalloc.a -l:libavro.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive -shared -fPIC -o tgt/Linux-x86_64/mylib/lib/mylib.so ./tgt/Linux-x86_64/mylib/obj/myfile.o ./tgt/Linux-x86_64/mylib/obj/myotherfile.o ./tgt/Linux-x86_64/mylib/obj/cJSON.o
/usr/bin/ld: ./tgt/Linux-x86_64/libmusl/lib/libc.a(exit.lo): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__fini_array_start' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tgt/Linux-x86_64/mylib/lib/mylib.so] Error 1
```

My musl build looks like:

```
cd mystatic_libs_build_dir/musl; \
./configure CFLAGS='-fPIC' \
--enable-shared \
--enable-static \
--prefix=/root/mylib/tgt/Linux-x86_64/libmusl; \
make; make install;
# libmusl is available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exit.lo will be written in assembler which is why your CFLAGS='-fPIC' is not having the effect you intend. This is either 1. a bug in 'musl' or 2. intentional and they do not support statically linking into .so's.

I would assume that it is unintentional and file a bug against 'musl'

You could also edit the asm yourself if you need a fix quickly.

Finally you might be able to configure musl to build with no asm?

Slightly off topic, but other options for a universal binary are:

1. Simply linking against glibc on the oldest version of Linux that you support.
2. Rather than struggling with a dependency on 'musl', simply use the Linux kernel api's directly.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile musl as long as your own code with `CFLAGS="-fPIC -Wa,-mrelax-relocations=no"` (your `binutils` version must be >=2.27).